# GIMP batch processing error

Tags: command-line, gimp

I have to use gimp batch processing mode in, but I have an error: batch command experienced an execution error
I use it to convert images to another format (fits to jpg). It says the images was converted, but there is nothing in the destination directory.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

```
(gimp:10595): GLib-WARNING **: goption.c:2168: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of type 0
batch command experienced an execution error
/media/disk/18/2018M/hmi.M_720s_nrt.20180120_050000_TAI.magnetogram.fits converted to /media/disk/18/2018M_jpg/hmi.M_720s_nrt.20180120_050000_TAI.magnetogram.jpg
```

Comment: An alternative is to use ImageMagick for batch processing. If you search the internet for **imagemagick tutorial**, you will find useful links, for example http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Comment: What gimp version? Is that actually an error, or just a warning? it looks like the conversion takes place regardless. This may be related: [Bug 1157037 - gimp shows warning on startup](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1157037#c2)